# sequential resolve, ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If any way to resolve calls into a state but sequential? meaning, I need to resolve one and the other just after the first is done?

let's say my configuration looks like this:

```
 $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
      url : '/',
      resolve : {
         firstCall : function(myService) {
             return myService.getSomething();
         },
         secondCall : function(differentService, $q) {
             //$q.when(myService.getSomething).getOther();
             return differentService.getOther();
         }
      }//others parameters are omited
   }
```

this is bad and I know it, but I've never done something similar into the resolve of the router.

Any guessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Chain** the two calls.

```
$stateProvider
   .state('home', {
      url : '/',
      resolve : {
         bothCalls : function(myService) {
             return myService.getSomething()
                 .then (function (result) {
                      var promise = differentService.getOther();
                      return $q.all([result, promise]);
                 });
         },
      }//others parameters are omited
   }
```

The `$q` service waits for the `getSomething` call to resolve before initiating the `getOther` call. The final result is an array with both results.